# symfony2 bundle class not getting autoloaded

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class that I want symfony2 to autoload so I can reference it from inside one of my registered services (I do not want to use the service container for this class).  I dropped it into src/{Vendor}/{BundleName}/Services but I'm getting a class not found exception.

Do I have to explicitly request that that directory gets autoloaded in autoload.php?

There's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you won't put this class in your bundle?

```
src/{BundleNamespace}/MyClass.php
or 
src/{BundleNamespace/MyClass/MyClass.php
```

If you want your class to be bundle independant, then put it in it's own bundle library:

```
src/MyLibrary/MyClass.php
```

You can now use

```
MyLibrary\MyClass()
```

The src directory is the fallback in the autoloader, so you wont need to explicitly declare its namespace there, however you will need to comply with [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)

Answer (score 0):

The namespace for my custom class was not correct.  If you're putting a file in src/{VENDOR}/{BundleName}/Services, you must use namespace {VENDOR}{BundleName}\Services